# Android N restarts the app when launching

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

When I try to run debug version app in **Android N** emulator, am getting an error that **"App getting Stop"**

This error show on the emulator as **Dialog box** with 3 sub options

1. Restart app
2. Close
3. Mute until device restart

This error occur when the **Display size is small**, when change the Dispaly size the app is working perfectly

**In Manifest**

**android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="24"**

am not getting Log, so i couldn't find what the error.

can any one please tell why this is happen.

Comment: Did you specify any screen requirements in the manifest?

Comment: No I didn't specify any screen requirements @Henry

Comment: Check your log, turn off filtering in Android Studio. If the app is crashing, there will be logcat output.

Comment: the app is working from eclipse @Larry Schiefer

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really help anyone in understanding what you're facing.  You need to post the logcat with the crash dump.  Eclipse also automatically filters logcat output, so you need to disable that and show logcat from everything.  Or, use logcat via adb at the command line to capture the crash.